# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(k(m-k))^p}{k! (m-k)!} (-1)^k$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics

A user posted this question the other day, but it was voluntary removed and it was of low quality, and I believe it's a useful question for those interested in combinatorics like myself

Show $$\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(k(m-k))^p}{k! (m-k)!} (-1)^k$$ is an integer where $m$ and $p$ are non-negative integers.

This series is inherently interesting, because while it is a sum of fractional terms, they appear to always magically cancel add up to an integer. For example, when $m=8$ and $p=4$, the series is
$$
-\frac{2401}{5040}+\frac{20736}{1440}-\frac{50625}{720}+\frac{65536}{576}-\frac{50625}{720}+\frac{20736}{1440}-\frac{2401}{5040}=1
$$
This looks like an extraordinary coincidence. Furthermore, I wrote a Python script to check the hypothesis for small values of $m$ and $p$, and the pattern persisted; the result is indeed always an integer for all $m$ and $p$ in the range $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$.

When I first saw this question, Stirling numbers of the second kind came to mind. Note the similarity to the Stirling numbers of the second kind, which are integers:
$${p\brace m} = \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (m-k)^p$$
Similarly, it is not obvious that the right hand side of the above expression always returns an integer, but it can be proven via a combinatorial argument using the principle of inclusion exclusion. Since the series in this question is a slight modification of the series defining ${p\brace m}$, the only difference being an additional factor of $k^p$ in each term, one might expect that there is also an underlying combinatorial interpretation for this series.

Comment: To a combinatorist, perhaps the originality could be debated if one is sufficiently familiar with related identities, but the interestingness ought to be self-evident: summing fractions shouldn't always result in an integer unless there's a reason (and combinatorics is very much concerned with finding such reasons). Especially when the sum is a convolution of such simple and suggestive summands like $k^p/k!$. While I feel this goes without saying, perhaps it would be prudent of OP to speak to it anyway, so as to not be collateral damage in the fight against low value PSQs.

Comment: @runway44 It might go without saying to someone who is well-versed in the particular theory.  But this site is for mathematics at all levels, and in any specialization.  A *good* question should convince a non-specialist of its value.  One should not have to be a specialist to understand why a question is interesting.

Comment: More generally, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \dfrac{P\left(k\right)}{k!\left(m-k\right)!} \left(-1\right)^k$ is an integer whenever $m \in \mathbb N$ and $P$ is any polynomial with integer coefficients. To see this, show it for $P\left(x\right) = x^i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$, or (even simpler) for $P\left(x\right) = x\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\cdots\left(x-i+1\right)$.

Answer (score 7):

First note we can write
$$\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(k(m-k))^p}{k! (m-k)!} (-1)^k = \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (k(m-k))^p$$

Note the similarity to the Stirling numbers of the second kind, which are integers:
$$\left\{{p\atop m}\right\} = \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (m-k)^p$$

If you write out the $k^p$ term as a polynomial in terms of $m-k$ using the binomial theorem, you get that the original sum is a linear combination of Stirling numbers of the second kind, like
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (k(m-k))^p\\
=& \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (m-k)^p (m - (m-k))^p\\
=& \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (m-k)^p \sum_{l=0}^p \binom{p}{l}m^{p-l}(-1)^l(m-k)^l\\
=& \sum_{l=0}^p(-1)^lm^{p-l}\binom{p}{l} \left(\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} (m-k)^{p+l}\right)\\
=& \sum_{l=0}^p(-1)^lm^{p-l}\binom{p}{l} \left\{{p+l\atop m}\right\}
\end{align*}

This implies the quantity in question is an integer